# Extract XML data in R from table on postgresql

Tags: r, regex, postgresql

I have a table on postgresql, which has an xml column and varchar/numeric columns. When trying to retrieve the data to save it into a data frame the xml is converted to character. Let's recreate the dataset:

```
my_dataset <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                         http_action = c("REQUEST","RESPONSE","REQUEST","RESPONSE","REQUEST","RESPONSE","REQUEST","RESPONSE","RESPONSE"),
                         http_data = c('"<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?> <questions> <candidate> <lastname>GOMEZ</lastname> <name>BARNEY</name> </candidate> </questions>)"',
                                       '"<validating> <opnum>123</opnum> <q1>Daily activity?</q1> <a1>Drinking at Moes</a1></validating>"',
                                       '"<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?> <questions> <option>1</option> </questions>"', 
                                       '"<validating> <code>XY936701</code> <date>12/03/2020</date> <time>19:07</time> <result>NONAUTHORIZED</result> <explanation>NON SUITABLE</explanation> </validating>"',
                                       '"<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?> <questions> <candidate> <lastname>LEONARD</lastname> <name>LEN</name> </candidate> </questions>)"' ,
                                       '"<validating> <opnum>124</opnum> <q1>Daily activity?</q1> <a1>Work at Nuclear Power</a1></validating>"',
                                       '"<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?> <questions> <option>1</option> </questions>"', 
                                       '"<validating> <code>XY936702</code> <date>15/03/2020</date> <time>16:12</time> <result>NONAUTHORIZED</result> <explanation>NON SUITABLE</explanation> </validating>"',
                                       '"<validating> <code>XY936702</code> <date>15/03/2020</date> <time>19:24</time> <result>AUTHORIZED</result> <explanation>SUITABLE</explanation> </validating>"'),
                         http_status = c(200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I receive the following warning:

```
In postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) :
  RS-DBI driver warning: (unrecognized PostgreSQL field type xml (id:142) in column 4)
```

I can extract the information using string comparisons on lines containing the node , I tried the following:

```
my_dataset <- my_dataset %>% 
mutate(authorized = ifelse(str_extract(http_data,"<result>[w+]</result>")=="",NA,
                           ifelse(str_extract(http_data,"<result>[w+]</result>")=="NONAUTHORIZED",0,1)))
```

As a result I get a full NA column, which is not what I expect. Please, could you help me with this question? I mean, perhaps my regex is not well written. And, do you know if it's possible to extract that information directly from the query? Thank you in advance for the help you can provide.

Regards

Comment: Hello @can, thank you, it's interesting that every time I put "an xml" my Mac suggest to write "a xml".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with your regex: it should be something like `<result>(\\w+)</result>`. Also to get the group matches `str_extract` is not enough. You can use `str_match` for groups. Take a look at `str_match` [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_match).

As an alternative solution, you can use an XML parser.

Comment: Hello @can, I start to figure out why my regex won't work, it doesn't extract the `(\\w+)` you suggest. One question, how can I use a xml parser, if that column came as char?

Comment: As a quick and dirty way, you can just do the comparisons like this: `str_extract(http_data,"<result>\\w+</result>")=="<result>NONAUTHORIZED</result>"`. And the for xml parser you can take a look at the documentations or maybe this link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_xml_files.htm

Comment: Hello @can, that way works fine, but do you know if I can extract just the text inside the tags?

Comment: Play around with `str_match` and the first regex i gave. `()` groups the part you actually want. With `str_match` you can see the group matches.